# How do I sign extend in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

Below is the code I have for my module:

```
module sext(input in[3:0], output out[7:0]);

    always_comb
        begin
            if(in[3]==1'b0)
                assign out = {4'b0000,in};
            else
                assign out = {4'b1111,in};
        end

endmodule
```

For some reason this is not working. Instead of sign extending it is zero extending. Any ideas to why this might be the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume you meant `(input [3:0] in, output [7:0] out)`. If that is true, then all you needed to write is

```
module sext(input signed [3:0] in, output signed [7:0] out);

    assign out = in;

endmodule
```

You could also write

```
module sext(input [3:0] in, output [7:0] out);

    assign out = 8'(signed'(in));

endmodule
```

And perhaps you don't even need to write this as a separate module.

Answer (score 2):

Few things you need to take care is,

1. you haven't declared a data type for `in` and `out`, so by default they are `wire` and `wire` can't be used at LHS inside procedural block. Refer Section `6.5 Nets and variables (SV LRM 1800-2012)`. So either use a continuous assignment or declare it as a variable (i.e. reg/logic etc.).
2. The assignment of `unpacked array` is illegal in your example, so either use `packed array` or follow the instructions given in Section `10.10 Unpacked array concatenation (SV LRM 1800-2012)`

Comment: I think it is  `default_nettype`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not illegal syntax but assign used inside an always block probably does not do what you think it does. Use assign for wires and do not use it inside initial or always.

You have defined your port ranges after the name, this results in 4 and 8 1-bit arrays rather than a 4 and 8 bit value.

You have used `{}` for concatination, but they can also be used for replication ie `{4{1'b1}}`.

```
module sext(
  input      [3:0] in, 
  output reg [7:0] out ); //ranged defined before name

  //No assign in always
  //concatenation with replication
  always_comb begin
    out = { {4{in[3]}}, in}; 
  end

endmodule
```

Or :

```
module sext(
  input      [3:0] in, 
  output     [7:0] out ); //out left as wire

  assign out = { {4{in[3]}}, in}; 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code.
There are some mistake in your code that you have to take care whiling writing the code.

1. You have use unpacked array so your targeted elements and actual elements are not match.
   ERROR : Number of elements in target expression does not match the number of 
   elements in source expression.

This error can solve by using packed array.So, your targeted elements and actual elements are matched.
Here is link from where you will get better understanding regarding packed and unpacked array.
LINK : [http://www.testbench.in/SV_09_ARRAYS.html][1]

2.Another thing that you have to take care is you are storing some value in out signal(variable) like assign out = {4'b0000,in}; 
 So you have to use reg data type to sore the value.
ERROR : Non reg type is not valid on the left hand side of this assignment
When you use reg data type then you can store value in out data type.

So, your problem is solved.

Here I also provide code which will run fine.

```
    module sext(input [3:0]in, output reg [7:0]out);

    always_comb
        begin
            if(in[3]==1'b0)
                assign out = {4'b0000,in};
            else
                assign out = {4'b1111,in};
        end

    endmodule
```